# Split query into two arguments using delimiter " " (space) - applescript

Tags: variables, split, applescript, osascript

I am trying to work out how I am able to split the query entered on run in applescript into two separate variables able to be operated on.

Example:

{query} = bob jane

variable1 = bob

variable2 = jane

I was looking into doing this as a wordlist but have been unsuccessful as it separates the query by other symbols apart from " " [space].

I am sorry, I am not very good with applescript and am very confused as to how to go about doing this. Thankyou for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
set input to "bob jane"
set the text item delimiters to space
set {var1, var2} to {text item 1, text item 2} of the input
```

`var1` will now be set to `"bob"`, and `var2` will be set to `"jane"`.

---

**Added 2020-10-26:**

Alternatively:

```
set input to "bob jane"
set {var1, var2} to the input's words
```

Comment: it says: [error "The variable Applescripts is not defined." number -2753 from "Applescripts"]
EDIT: think it was just a grammatical error, think it should be *Applescript's* instead of *Applescripts's*

Comment: All good xD Im very bad at applescript but that didnt really make sense to me. Thankyou for your help!